# Estimation in multivariate normal

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

I need to show $\underline{\hat{\mu}}=\underline{\bar{y}}$:

$$L(y_1, y_2, ...) = \prod _{i=1}^n f(y_i,\underline{\mu},\underline{\Sigma})$$

$$ = \prod _{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\biggl(\sqrt{2 \pi}\biggl)^p |\Sigma|^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y_i -\mu)'\Sigma ^{-1}(y_i -\mu)} $$

Taking log:

$$= -np \log{\biggl(\sqrt{2\pi}\biggl)}-\frac{n}{2}\log{(\Sigma)}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i -\mu)'\Sigma ^{-1}(y_i -\mu)$$

Maximising:

$$ 0 = \frac{-1}{2} \times 2 \sum^{n}_{i=1} (y_i -\mu)$$

Then, I do not know how to proceed. 
I presume

$$ n\mu =\sum^{n}_{i=1} y_i $$

Comment: After $116$ questions and $65$ answers, I would thought you'd have had enough opportunity to familiarize yourself with how we typeset math on this site. Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). In particular, double dollar signs yield displayed equations, which are much easier to read, especially when they heavily mix fractions, subscripts, superscripts and radicals as in your case; and operator names should be in Roman font, using e.g. `\log`, or `\operatorname{name}` for operators that don't have a command of their own.

Comment: Advice is well received, and editing done also. Sometimes a bit of sarcasm can change so much. :P

Comment: It looks like the last statement immediately follows from the previous.  What are you looking for?

Comment: It would help if you explicitly defined $\hat{\mu}$ and $\bar{y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done everything correct. You've reached 
$$0 = \frac{-1}{2} \times 2 \sum^{n}_{i=1} (y_i -\mu)$$
or more formally (since your maximum is attained at the MLE)
$$0 = \frac{-1}{2} \times 2 \sum^{n}_{i=1} (y_i - \hat{\mu})$$
where $\hat{\mu}$ is your MLE. Then 
$$0 =  \sum^{n}_{i=1} (y_i - \hat{\mu})$$
i.e.
$$0 =  \sum^{n}_{i=1} y_i -\sum^{n}_{i=1}  \hat{\mu}$$
But $\hat{\mu}$ is a constant being summed up $n$ times, so
$$0 =  \sum^{n}_{i=1} y_i - n \hat{\mu}$$
Finally,
$$\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} y_i = \bar{y}$$
is the MLE estimate, i.e. the sample mean of the data is the MLE estimate of $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for a  vector $x \in \mathbb{R} ^ p$, and real symmetric matrix $A$,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x ^ T A x = 2 A x,
$$
hence, 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \ln L ( \cdot ; \mu, \Sigma )
 =
\sum \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}(y_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (y_i-\mu) =  - \Sigma^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\mu) = 0,
$$
multiplying by $\Sigma$ and re-arranging the equation you get 
$$
\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i.
$$
Don't forget that $y_i$ are vectors, hence $\hat{\mu}$ is $p \times 1$ vector of sample means.